# Spam Account on Site

Tags: discussion, support

I have encountered this spam account that seems to be only be used to promote a business. Can the account be suspended?

https://money.stackexchange.com/users/14581/user14581

Comment: The account has been deleted.

Answer (score 8):

We got it.  Thanks for the heads up.

For the record, the flagging system is a bit more effective than a meta post; flag it at spam and you can move on.  My understanding is all it takes is a few flags before the account is punish the account system wide.  SE is pretty proactive about spam.

You flag it and either a mod or the system will take care of them.

Comment: Late comment, but this isn't entirely true. In fact, if an account's post gets deleted as spam, then 100 rep is deducted from it and the account goes to a black list, but only on the community the spam was posted on.